# ASP.NET Core route giving 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC web site, and have the following routes...

```
routes.MapRoute("campaign", "{code}/{teamID}/{action=Index}/{controller=Campaign}");
routes.MapRoute("campaign", "{code}/{action=Index}/{controller=Campaign}");
```

...with the following controller method...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string code, int? teamID)
```

This means that the following mappings work...

```
/fred -> /Campaign/Index?code=fred
/fred/123 -> /Campaign/Index?code=fred&teamID=123
```

I now want to add a route to do the following...

```
/fred/Team/123 -> /Team/Index?code=fred&ID=123
```

I added the following route...

```
routes.MapRoute("team", "{code}/Team/{id}/{controller=Team}");
```

...and the following to my TeamController...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string code, int id)
```

...but when I try to access `/fred/Team/123` I get a 404.

Anyone able to explain what I've done wrong?

Comment: Your routing setup is odd, but the specific problem you have is that you don't have a `{action=Index}` for the route that's not working.

Comment: @KirkLarkin You just beat me to it! If you'd like to add that as an answer (maybe put in a line of code to clarify), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to include the action in the route. The following works as I wanted...

```
routes.MapRoute("team", "{code}/Team/{id}/{action=Index}/{controller=Team}");
```

Thanks to @KirkLarkin who posted this as a comment at the same time as I came back to report I'd found the same answer :)